# How to uninstall applications when the system is missing uninstall meta data?

Tags: uninstall, cleaning

I have a computer where somebody seems to have deleted the uninstall meta data from Microsoft project and other apps.

I really need to clean up all the crap in the registry and basically do the best uninstall possbile.

What's a good tool to scan for cruft that can be uninstalled?

Answer (score 6):

Try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html).

Comment: +1, Used to run CCleaner for this too, But Revo is much better. CCleaner has its own uses in other ways.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft provides an [Installer Clean Up](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301) utility that may be all you need.  A popular third-party tool is [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) - a tool that also lets you set your start-up programs.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good results with registry mechanic.  It analyzes the registry and looks for a plethora of common problems like this.

http://www.pctools.com/registry-mechanic/